# bibtex, bibliographic style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am currently using bibtex to create a bibliography, but I want to change the appearance. I want it to be like this:

`Last name, initials from first name. (year): Title. *Journal*, **volume**, pp. page from - page to.`

I currently have

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

in my `master`, and

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{lit}
```

in my `include-document`.

What can I change, to get the desired look?

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE.
Perhaps you should show what you have tried to reach the disired goal. Showing the work done on the matter is usually considered good practice around here and can be very useful to help you improve on it.

Comment: I have tried changing the bibliographystyle to apa, apalike etc., but nothing seems to work. I managed to make the code above work, but every time I change something I end in trouble

Comment: Why don't you try with `biblatex`? It's much easier.

Comment: You probably need to think a little harder about your bibliographical requirements.  A style that caters *only* to the `@article` type is likely seriously deficient for most serious use.